# lua match everything after a tag in a string

Tags: lua, string-matching, findinfiles

The string is like this:
TEMPLATES="!$TEMPLATE templatename manufacturer model mode\n$TEMPLATE MacQuantum Wash Basic\n$$MANUFACTURER Martin\n$$MODELNAME Mac Quantum Wash\n$$MODENAME Basic\n"

My way to get strings without tags is:

```
    local sentence=""
    for word in string.gmatch(line,"%S+") do
      if word ~= tag then
        sentence=sentence .. word.." "
      end              
    end
    table.insert(tagValues, sentence)
    E(tag .." --> "..sentence)
```

And I get output:

```
$$MANUFACTURER --> Martin 
$$MODELNAME --> Mac Quantum Wash 
... 
...
```

But this is not the way I like. 
I would like to find first the block starting with $TEMPLATE tag to check if this is the right block. There is many such blocks in a file I read line by line. Then I have to get all tags marked with double $: $$MODELNAME etc. 
I have tried it on many ways, but none satisfied me. Perhaps someone has an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Can you add to your question an example of the desired output?

Comment: Desired outputs are tags values, exactly like I posted: for tag $$MANUFACTURER I want to get Martin, and so on.

Comment: I mean can you add that too your question, like how you have the output you are getting right now, what would that look like if it was the output you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are going to use Lua [patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) (like regex, but different) inside a function string.gmatch, which creates a loop.
Explanation:
`for match in string.gmatch(string, pattern) do print(match) end` is an iterative function that will iterate over every instance of `pattern` in `string`. The pattern I will use is `%$+%w+%s[^\n]+`

`%$+` - At least 1 literal $ ($ is a special character so it needs the % to escape), + means 1 or more. You could match for just one ("%$") if you only need the data of the tag but we want information on how many $ there are so we'll leave that in.

`%w+` - match any alphanumeric character, as many as appear in a row.

`%s` - match a single space character

`[^\n]+` - match anything that isn't '\n' (^ means invert), as many as appear in a row. 
Once the function hits a \n, it executes the loop on the match and repeats the process.

That leaves us with strings like "$TEMPLATE templatename manufacturer"
We want to extract the $TEMPLATE to its own variable to verify it, so we use `string.match(string, pattern)` to just return the value found by the pattern in string.

OK: EDIT: Here's a comprehensive example that should provide everything you're looking for.

```
templates = "!$TEMPLATE templatename manufacturer model mode\n$TEMPLATE MacQuantum Wash Basic\n$$MANUFACTURER Martin\n$$MODELNAME Mac Quantum Wash\n$$MODENAME Basic\n"

local data = {}
for match in string.gmatch(templates, "%$+%w+%s[^\n]+") do --finds the pattern given in the variable 'templates'
  --this function assigns certain data to tags inside table t, which goes inside data.
 local t = {}
 t.tag = string.match(match, '%w+')  --the tag (stuff that comes between a $ and a space)
 t.info = string.gsub(match, '%$+%w+%s', "") --value of the tag (stuff that comes after the `$TEMPLATE `. Explanation: %$+ one or more dollar signs $w+ one or more alphanumeric characters $s a space. Replace with "" (erase it)
 _, t.ds = string.gsub(match, '%$', "") --This function emits two values, the first one is garbage and we don't need (hence a blank variable, _). The second is the number of $s in the string).
 table.insert(data, t)
end
for _,tag in pairs(data) do     --iterate over every table of data in data.
 for key, value in pairs(tag) do
  print("Key:", key, "Value:", value) --this will show you data examples (see output)
 end
 print("-------------")
end

print('--just print the stuff with two dollar signs')
for key, data in pairs(data) do
 if data.ds == 2 then --'data' becomes a subtable in table 'data', we evaluate how many dollar signs it recognized.
  print(data.tag)
 end
end

print("--just print the MODELNAME tag's value")
for key, data in pairs(data) do
 if data.tag == "MODELNAME" then --evaluate the tag name.
  print(data.info)
 end
end
```

Output:

```
Key:    info    Value:  templatename manufacturer model mode
Key:    ds  Value:  1
Key:    tag Value:  TEMPLATE
-------------
Key:    info    Value:  MacQuantum Wash Basic
Key:    ds  Value:  1
Key:    tag Value:  TEMPLATE
-------------
Key:    info    Value:  Martin
Key:    ds  Value:  2
Key:    tag Value:  MANUFACTURER
-------------
Key:    info    Value:  Mac Quantum Wash
Key:    ds  Value:  2
Key:    tag Value:  MODELNAME
-------------
Key:    info    Value:  Basic
Key:    ds  Value:  2
Key:    tag Value:  MODENAME
-------------
--just print the stuff with two dollar signs
MANUFACTURER
MODELNAME
MODENAME
--just print the MODELNAME tag's value:
Mac Quantum Wash
```